# JavaFx Not able to pass a value from a class to configure setScene

Tags: java, javafx

I am a Newbie trying to learn java and I am a complete beginner at java Fx so please forgive the noob question but I am trying to structure my code more cleanly by having all my buttons in a class but I know that I have to have the variable 'button' in a StackPane but when I do it it tells me that java can't find the variable. if someone can help me then that would be greatly appreciated. (also when the button is not in another class the code worked)

```
    //this class is for drawing the buttons
    public void Buttons() {
        Button button = new Button("My Button");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //this sets the Title for the window
        primaryStage.setTitle("Calcultor");
        //this calls the class that draws the buttons on screen
        Buttons();
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(button);
        //this cerates a stage and sets the window size
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 400));
        //this refreshes the window
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: As posted `Buttons` is not a class but a method. I think you want Buttons to return a button, and then use it: `Button button = Buttons();`. Also try to stick to [java naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/). For more help post [mre]

Comment: I Got it to work using an different method. thank you for Helping me also yeah I was thinking that my code that I included would not be enough.